# Format single line of code with spaces and linebreaks

Tags: formatting

Is there any quick way converting

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><response><id>0123456</id><userid>0123</userid>
```

to

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
      <response>
        <id>
          0123456
        </id>
        <userid>
          0123
        </userid>
```

?

preferably client-side (JS) way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Parsing%20XML) will do it. Not always perfectly, but it does okay. It's available in Python and Ruby though, not JS.

<strike>ETA: I just found a pretty cool [js + CSS solution](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html) from Google that does indentation and colours for XML and a dozen other things (such as js). It's really pretty.</strike>  Nevermind. It doesn't handle xml indentation.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a link that shows how to use jQuery to parse XML (All client side, with an AJAX call to load the XML).

If you don't want an AJAX call, load the XML into a JS string and follow the tutorial.

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/xml-parsing-with-jquery